# how to set result of aggregate sql query as lable caption

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am using this code to retrieve no of machines (count)...

```
    Dim strCntSr As String = "SELECT count(sr_no) FROM Vendor_Machine WHERE chaln_no='" & cmbChal_no.Text & "'"
    comm_getCnt = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strCntSr, cnnOLEDB)
    comm_getCnt.ExecuteNonQuery()

    ***Here I want to set result of the above query [count(sr_no)] as text of lblMachine***

    lblMachine.Text =
```

Please suggest me the code.. Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) return only the number of the rows affected not the value/s returned by the query.
In your case the correct method to use is [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) that returns the first column of the first row obtained by the query.

Notice also that is a very bad practice to build query text using string concatenation.
The problems are [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and correct parsing of text provided by you.

```
Dim strCntSr As String = "SELECT count(sr_no) FROM Vendor_Machine WHERE chaln_no=?"
comm_getCnt = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strCntSr, cnnOLEDB)
comm_getCnt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cmbChal_no.Text)
Dim result = comm_getCnt.ExecuteScalar()
lblMachine.Text = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```